# Multi-line text view has two different behaviours

Tags: android, textview

I want the text in my text-view to wrap when it is too long. When I first open the activity the extra text is not visible. When I turn the phone the text fits. When I turn it back again the text is wrapped, but the tops and bottoms of the text are cut off. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Also, why do I get different behaviour when I open the activity and after turning it back to vertical?
[image: pic 1] [image: pic 2] [image: pic 3]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_height"
android:background="@color/color_accent_two">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:background="@color/color_accent_two">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tajikTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="@color/color_accent_one"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/englishTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="@color/color_accent_three"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tajikLatinTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="@color/color_accent_three"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Apply top and bottom padding to your textview if they cut from top and bottom.

Comment: I tried adding padding to the top textView. The padding is added, but the text is still cut off.

Comment: Why you use android:layout_weight="1" for all textview. Their is no need to use this.

Comment: I'll remove that. Thanks.

Comment: I removed android:layout_weight="1". And then I changed android:layout_height to "wrap_content". Now it looks perfect. Thanks

Comment: you can accepted the answer so other can found this post helpful and from the moderator side they can close this question. I up voted your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:
Remove the weight and set TextView height wrap_content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_accent_two"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_accent_two"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tajikTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/color_accent_one"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/englishTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/color_accent_three" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tajikLatinTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/color_accent_three" />
</LinearLayout>
```